# Unable to play DVDs

Tags: dvd

I'm a newbie, and I've installed the restricted extras package but I still cant play a dvd. Is there a way to trouble shoot the problem or is there any important codecs that I've missed?

Comment: just install vlc or smplayer

Answer (score 1):

VLC and SMPLAYER both are very good media player and support almost every audio/video format. If you install them then you can run dvd without install external plugins.

> install vlc    (25-30 MB): `sudo apt-get install vlc`
>   install smplayer (8.5 MB): `sudo apt-get install smplayer`

OR just search in synaptic package manager or Ubuntu software center.

Answer (score 1):

You should also run the command `sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh` to be able to play in the default movie player.